# Am I using np.searchsorted() right?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, binary-search

I have a list of integers and I thought I could use [np.searchsorted()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html#numpy.searchsorted) to perform a binary search to look for the the closest integer. So, I tried,

```py
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> B = [0, 36, 75, 111, 162, 198, 237, 273]
>>> np.searchsorted(B, 210)
6
>>> B[np.searchsorted(B, 210)]
237
```

Should the closest neighbour of 210 not be 198? Is there a native Python 3 library that does what I want? I could implement it myself but I am looking a fastest implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think `np.argmin()` is proper for your purpose.

Try this code.

```
import numpy as np
B = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]) 
criterion = 4 

ind = np.argmin(np.abs(B - criterion)) # find the index i, where i'th element is the closest to criterion
print(B[ind])
```